# Is masking needed for prediction in LSTM keras

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, keras

I am trying to do sentence generator using 50D word embedding. If my training sentence is "`hello my name is abc`" here max words is 5. So my first training x is `[0,0,0,0,hello]` and target is `[my]` second x would be `[0,0,0,hello,my]` target is `[name]` and so on...

To generate given sentence should I give `[hello]` or with padding `[0,0,0,0,hello]`?

Comment: It depends on what problem you're trying to solve. Why is simulating variable-length sequences important to your problem? How is it related to the predictions that you want to make? Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: This question seems to arise from the choice to enforce fixed-length sequences instead of using variable-length sequences.

Comment: I've merged this with your previously asked and deleted question. Deleting and re-asking closed questions works against how stats.SE is designed to operate because it destroys the contributions made by other users. Please refrain from deleting closed questions in the future, and instead revise the closed post so that it may be reopened. For more information, please see the [help].